# Is it possible to match on clap's ArgMatches type?

Tags: rust, clap

Is it possible to match on clap's `ArgMatches` type like

```
match matches {
   "arg1" => doSomething(),
   "arg2" => doSomethingElse(),
   // ...
}
```

or must one use the syntax described in the documentation

```
if matches.is_present("arg1") {
    doSomething();
} else if matches.is_present("arg2") {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

I find the second form much wordier than even a case statement.

Comment: If the verbosity is an issue, perhaps you could try the [structopt crate](https://crates.io/crates/structopt) instead. It will parse into a struct so you don't have to do any work to check if values are present etc.

Comment: [Is there a way to use custom patterns such as a regex or functions in a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43211180/155423)

Comment: @PeterHall The structopt crate is a great find. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Argument Matching

It is not possible to use pattern matching on the `ArgMatches` because it is not an Enum type. Furthermore, you can retrieve only one argument at a time. Therefore, only conditional statements can be used in this case:

```rust
use clap::{Arg, Command};

fn main() {
    let matches = Command::new("command")
        .arg(
            Arg::new("arg1")
                .short('1')
                .long("arg1")
                .help("Argument one help message")
                .default_value("one"), // Comment this line out to test other branches
        )
        .arg(
            Arg::new("arg2")
                .short('2')
                .long("arg2")
                .help("Argument two help message"),
        )
        .get_matches_from(vec!["command", "--arg2", "two"]); // Remove the arg2 to test the default case

    if matches.contains_id("arg1") {
        println!("Values are present for arg1");
    } else if matches.contains_id("arg2") {
        println!("Values are present for arg2");
    } else {
        println!("No values are present for arg1 and arg2");
    }
}
```

In this code, there are the `arg1` and the `arg2` argument under the `command` command. The first argument has a default values, and the second argument's value is set in the command line. You can pass arguments and values using the `get_matches_from` method.

> Note: In this setup, you can only do one thing. When `arg1` is given then the other conditions are not executed. If you would like to do multiple thing once an argument is present, use **single condition** instead of multiple conditions.

If you want to pass the values and the arguments in terminal, replace the `get_matches_from` with the `get_matches` method. And execute the following command in your terminal:

```bash
cargo run -- --arg1 1 --arg2 2
```

The first double slash (`--`) separates the arguments between the Cargo and your command argument.

However, there are some use-case where you can use pattern matching.

### Value Source Matching

The first use-case is for [ValueSource](https://docs.rs/clap/4.4.7/clap/parser/enum.ValueSource.html) Enum type. You can match on the different value sources. For example, the argument's value can be set from the command-line, the environment variable, or the default value. Here is a code snippet that shows the usage:

```
    let arg1 = matches.value_source("arg1").unwrap();
    let arg2 = matches.value_source("arg2").unwrap();

    match arg1 {
        ValueSource::DefaultValue => println!("Using default value"),
        ValueSource::EnvVariable => println!("Using environment variable"),
        ValueSource::CommandLine => println!("Using command-line argument"),
        _ => println!("Using other value source"),
    }

    match arg2 {
        ValueSource::DefaultValue => println!("Using default value"),
        ValueSource::EnvVariable => println!("Using environment variable"),
        ValueSource::CommandLine => println!("Using command-line argument"),
        _ => println!("Using other value source"),
    }
```

As you can see, we have to get each argument one-by-one, then match them across the `ValueSource` variant.

### Sub-command Matching

The other is the [Subcommands](https://docs.rs/clap/4.4.7/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#subcommands) use-case. Code snippet example for the sub-commands:

```
    let matches = Command::new("command")
        .subcommand(Command::new("subcommand1"))
        .subcommand(Command::new("subcommand2"))
        .subcommand(Command::new("subcommand3"))
        .get_matches_from(vec!["command", "subcommand2"]); // Change this for testing the different subcommands

    match matches.subcommand() {
        Some(("subcommand1", sub_matches)) => println!("subcommand1 was used"),
        Some(("subcommand2", sub_matches)) => println!("subcommand2 was used"),
        Some(("subcommand3", sub_matches)) => println!("subcommand3 was used"),
        _ => println!("default case"),
    }
```

You can use pattern matching on `subcommand` method because it returns with `Option` Enum type.