# How to match all whitespace?

Tags: rust

**Context**: Rust has the `match` construct, which is really useful to make a (possibly) exhaustive list of cases and their corresponding results. The problem is: how do I create a case which encompasses a subset of many cases?

Regarding my specific problem, I'm making a lexer which reads a string character-by-character and spits out tokens. Its main function looks like this:

```rs
(...)
    fn new(input: &str) -> Lexer {
        let mut characters = input.chars();
        for c in characters {
            let mut token: Option<Token> = match c {
                '+' => Some(Token::Add),
                '-' => Some(Token::Minus),
                '*' => Some(Token::Mul),
                '/' => Some(Token::Div),
                'e' => Some(Token::EulersNum),
                'π' => Some(Token::Pi),
                '(' => Some(Token::LeftParen),
                ')' => Some(Token::RightParen),
                ' ' | '\t' | '\n' => continue, //Whitespace
                _ => None
            };

            if token == None {
                continue;
            }
        }

        todo!()
    }
(...)
```

Now, the most important part, for the purposes of this question, is the one commented with 'Whitespace'. The problem with my handling of the whitespaces is that it may not correspond to the actual implementation of whitespaces in a given string format. Sure, I could handle all of the different kinds of ascii whitespaces, but what about Unicode? Making an exhaustive list of whitespaces is something that is not only cumbersome, but also something that obfuscates the code. It should be left to the language, not to it's users.

Is it possible to just match it with a 'Whitespace' expression, such as:

```rs
(...)

Whitespace => continue,

(...)
```

And if so, how do I do it?

Comment: This isn't really the right level of abstraction. Just write a function that determines whether or not something is whitespace, and use an if statement.

Comment: This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211909/9306292). If you _really_ must save the function call, copy the code from standard library.

Comment: `Making an exhaustive list of whitespaces is something that is not only cumbersome, but also something that obfuscates the code. It should be left to the language, not to it's users.` No. Really no. It should be left to the libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`char::is_whitespace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_whitespace) in a match guard:

```
match c {
    '+' => Some(Token::Add),
    '-' => Some(Token::Minus),
    '*' => Some(Token::Mul),
    '/' => Some(Token::Div),
    c if c.is_whitespace() => Some(Token::Whitespace),
    _ => None,
};
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2df4c97a53dfdd9f18411bfe1a3fd077)

Comment: This was the most helpful answer. It's simple, and shows exactly the intent in code. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> Sure, I could handle all of the different kinds of ascii whitespaces, but what about Unicode?

Use a library that provides a `is_whitespace()` function for many string formats or more complex matching capabilities, if you need it.

Otherwise, use functions like `char::is_whitespace()` if you just need to match against Unicode whitespace.

> Making an exhaustive list of whitespaces is something that is not only cumbersome, but also something that obfuscates the code. It should be left to the language, not to it's users.

No, a `match` (and pattern matching etc.) are general tools. Rust is not a language specialized for language or string processing. Thus adding support for "whitespace matching" to pattern matching does not make sense.

Rust has basic ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16 etc. support for practical reasons, but that's about it. Adding complex bits part of the standard library is debatable.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but: I don't get your first sentence. What should an external crate provide, what `char::is_whitespace` doesn't provide? The char one is unicode aware, so that's not the deal. Second rust "support" for ASCII and UTF-16 is... spare? I mean, there are `char::is_ascii_whitespace` yes. But every `String`, `str` and `char` in Rust is UTF-8. If you need other interpretations you have to use an external crate. Also Ivan showed an example on how to do it properly, so that could also be in your answer.

Comment: The question is essentially "How to match all whitespace characters in one arm of a match expression?". This answer starts off with "use external library", without explaining how that would allow to match all whitespace in one match arm, then goes on to discuss how `match` isn't supposed to be a tool for this job.

Comment: @hellow The question talks about not just ASCII or Unicode, but "*several string formats*" too. Thus I read the question as a more abstract "why a language like Rust does not allow more string/complex/regex/... pattern matching?". Since the duplicate was already tagged anyway and the other answer already said the very same thing, I preferred to discuss in the answer what was wrong with OP's perspective.